# rails: pictures do not show up on heroku, but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My pictures show up locally, but after pushing to Heroku, they don't show up.

I have tried different paths.

This is the image tags:

```html
<img alt="ava" src="/assets/ava.jpg" />
```

The strange thing is, the directory tree in Rails is like this `app/assets/images/ava.jpg` however, if I put this (correct) path, the images do not even show up locally.

After precompiling the assets, the images appear in `public/assets/ava-xteohutnbhueb.jpg` which means they got extra token at the end of their names.

When the app is pushed to heroku, the images do not show up at all, either with `src="/assets/ava.jpg"` or `src="/assets/images/ava.jpg"`

Why do they show up locally with wrong paths and why don't they show up on Heroku?

Comment: now they only show the path of the compiled images: ```assets/ava-teaseutnbkuena.jpg``` instead of the picture

Comment: ah okay cool, I got it now, i put ```image_tag``` instead of ```image_path``` and it works. do you want to put your comment into an answer so I can mark it complete?

Comment: Yes, i want. give me moment :)

Comment: Vishal got it right, Heroku is serving your cached version of your static assets and you need to precompile it to bust those old caches.

It is also common to precompile these assets locally with `rails assets:precompile` before pushing to `heroku`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all precompile assets of the project with below command

```
 heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

and then use below command

```
<%= image_tag("ava.jpg") %>
```